# PHP instantiation breaks the script with AJAX call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, response

I called a PHP script with jQuery but it doesn't return any response if i instantiate a class before echo-ing the response. Meaning that it works if i instantiate the object after.

javascript code :

```
$.post('libraries/test.php', {action: 'duplicateForm', service: service_name}, function(response)
{
    console.log(response);
});
```

php script:

```
$response = '1';
$f = new usvn_form_insert();
$response = '2';
echo $response;
```

I don't use the `$_POST` variables in this test. With this, the response is empty but if I put the echo before `$f = new usvn_form_insert();` it prints 1

Comment: What is your error reporting set to in php.ini? It is likely you are getting a fatal error or something from that class that is not outputted to the browser.

Comment: Do you have access to the server error logs? There should be a message there. One of several things is happening : the usvn_form_insert object isn't available due to a missing include, the constructor expects args, or the constructor is failing for reasons we can only guess at without an error message.

Comment: Obviously there is some problem when instantiating of the object. Try looking inside its constructor, checking whether Your `usvn_form_insert` class exists (when on UNIX system, letter cases must also match), etc... Providing us the error report would be appreciated...

Comment: I love when people call them 'easy ones' but they are on this site asking anyway...

Comment: my reporting error is set to E_ALL. And there is no error, the class exists and the include is ok, the constructor doesn't expect args. It does the same thing if i write a require_once instead of an instantiation

Answer (score 1):

Put error_reporting(E_ALL) at the top of your php script and see if it returning any error back to the browser.